# emacs failing to run c:\.emacs

Tags: init-file

I have been using emacs for a long time in windows.
(windows 10 on an HP laptop PC)  My .emacs file is in c:.emacs.

Up until yesterday, the file was run whenever I started up emacs.
But yesterday it failed to run, so I have to manually run it.

The .emacs (and _emacs) file is visible within emacs when I do a directory listing of c:

-rw-rw-rw-  1 Ray Voith        None           6670 2014-06-14  .emacs

-rw-rw-rw-  1 Ray Voith        None           6605 2014-06-14  _emacs

but is not visible within cygwin in directory /cygdrive/c
I tried chmod 777 .emacs (also chmod 777 _emacs) within cygwin but it says

$ chmod 777 _emacs

chmod: changing permissions of ‘_emacs’: Permission denied

Ray Voith@laptop /cygdrive/c

$ chmod 777 .emacs

chmod: cannot access ‘.emacs’: No such file or directory

I have not intentionally done anything to the .emacs file.

Does anyone know why emacs would all of a sudden stop executing .emacs?

Comment: Not sure why it worked before and then stopped working

Answer (score 2):

Set your MS Windows **`HOME`** environment variable to point to the folder where you store your init file (e.g., `.emacs`). This is apparently `C:\`, for you.

`C:\` is the place where users put their init files in the past, but it is not necessarily the best place to do so. I recommend that you do this:

1. Set your to `HOME` environment variable to something like `d:\usr\yourusername\`.  Your user name here can be any name you like. In other words, just set `HOME` to some folder explicitly.

   You can use `System` > `Advanced system settings` > `Environment Variables` > `User Variables` to do this.  Just add a `HOME` variable if none is there.
2. Be sure to make yourself the *owner* of that entire folder, including all its subfolders.